# How to read and execute python script stored in memory from node js app

Tags: python, node.js, memory, filesystems

I have node JS application where I am storing python file on filesystem and execute that python script stored in filesystem and log the output as well using

```
const scriptExecution = spawn('python', ['-u', pythonfilePath]);
scriptExecution.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
}
```

but my pythonfilePath is path from filesystem .

So is there any way where I read python file content from DB and store file in  memory using **memfs**
and execute python script. so instead of filesystem can I use memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me

```
// testnodepy.js

const { spawn } = require('node:child_process');

pycode = `print("hello")
print("world")`
const ls = spawn('python', ['-c', pycode]);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

> node testnodepy.js
stdout: hello
world
```

Comment: Thanks you @Rahul, its working but i am getting only first log in stdout, is there any other param required

Comment: probably share your python code (minimal) so some one have a look.

Comment: Above code worked as expected, instead of python code is there any way to execute javascript code

Comment: You can just use eval() function to evaluate JavaScript provided that the code is received from safer place where you have control.

Comment: I want to just execute   jscode = `console.log("log from DB function!");
  console.log(`{ "return": "Return from DB function!" } `);` and print the logs also in stdout

Comment: Its probably worth asking another question